# FirebaseRemoteConfigClientException: Firebase Installations failed to get installation auth token for fetch

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm getting exception as

```
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigClientException: Firebase Installations failed to get installation auth token for fetch.
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?
I've initialised remote config like this

```
val firebaseRemoteConfig: FirebaseRemoteConfig by lazy { FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance() }

val firebaseRemoteConfigSettings = FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
        .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(0)
        .build()
firebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(firebaseRemoteConfigSettings)
    firebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(configDefault)
 if (NetworkConnectionHelper().connectionStatus(context)) {
        firebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
                .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<Boolean?> ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        setup()
                        Utils.log("remoteConfig Success.")

                    } else {
                        Utils.log("remoteConfig failed.")
                        setup()
                    }

                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception -> Utils.log("remoteConfig exception: $exception") }
                .addOnCanceledListener { Utils.log("remoteConfig initAssetList: cancelled ") }
    } else {
        setup()
    }
```

What I've tried so far

1. I've added SHA1 Key to Google Api & services, under "Restrict usage to your Android apps" section
2. Uninstall and install the app.
3. Added SHA1 key in firebase console.
4. tried with only "fetch()" method of remoteconfig instead of fetchAndActivie().

but nothing help, I'm unable to fetch values from remote config.

Comment: please post full error log

Comment: @Priyankagb I'm not getting error, I'm getting exception and I've printed exception in log, I've updated my question with exception message.

Answer (score 6):

I was also facing a similar issue on one of the devices and found out that that device is not having a google play store account logged in. When I tried the phone with a google play store account logged in, it worked. I wasted a few hours finding this. I hope if saves your time if facing the same issue.

Comment: but the question may be different - why does it crash the app? it should not crash the app...

Answer (score 1):

Go to [google cloud credential section](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) & make sure if you have your keys restricted then these APIs are also selected. For me, Firebase Installations API was causing the issue.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Finally after spending whole day I found the mistake, it was my spell mistake in package name while adding SHA-1 in Google's api & services portal.
Thanks anyway.