# Token exceptions are coming for Firebase Remote APIs after update of google-services.json

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Exception:

> com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigClientException: Firebase Installations failed to get installation auth token for fetch.

Troubleshooting steps I've tried:

1. Checked with 4.3.13 to 4.3.15 com.google.gms.google-services Working fine with older google-services.json
2. Checked with remote config
   downgrade dependency versions also Tested with Physical / emulator
   device
3. Checked configuration on Google cloud dashboard
4. There is no
   issue that with emulators
5. SHA-1 is registered. It is working for one Android Studio, but not working with another Android Studio.

Checked all this answers:
[FirebaseRemoteConfigClientException: Firebase Installations failed to get installation auth token for fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65404359/firebaseremoteconfigclientexception-firebase-installations-failed-to-get-instal)

[Firebase remote config fetch failed with FirebaseRemoteConfigClientException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65823846/firebase-remote-config-fetch-failed-with-firebaseremoteconfigclientexception)

[Firebase not working com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549408/firebase-not-working-com-google-firebase-installations-firebaseinstallationsexce)

[Not connecting to services like Play Store or FirebaseRemoteConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73202693/not-connecting-to-services-like-play-store-or-firebaseremoteconfig)

[Firebase Remote Config Fetch failed with user not authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54603283/firebase-remote-config-fetch-failed-with-user-not-authorized)

[Using Google Firebase Remote Config without Google Play Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60741260/using-google-firebase-remote-config-without-google-play-services)

[Firebase Remote Config fetch fails on devices without play services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64554831/firebase-remote-config-fetch-fails-on-devices-without-play-services)

Please help!